# What is the correct property name for firebase auth photoURL?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

All of the [firebase authentication documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_a_users_profile) refers to this property as `photoURL` ('URL' is uppercase), but when I export user data to json, the property is `photoUrl` (camelCased). Is this just a quirk of the export process or has the property name changed throughout firebase?

Comment: How are you exporting the user data to json? If you are using auth:export, the docs say the format is "photoUrl": photo-url [auth:export](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/auth)

Comment: So they do. (I am using auth:export). I could delete this question or you could answer with "It's photoURL unless accessed via auth:export in the CLI" and I will accept it @Jay